# large matrix computation

Tags: c++

I write a simple code in C++ and I compile it with g++ on linux ubuntu 11.04 and I don't get any errors but when I run the executable file, I get this error "segmentation fault".

I know that my code has no problem and tHat this error is related to the compiler.

Can somebody help me?

**My code is :**

```
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    double a[200][200][200],b[200][200][200],c[200][200][200];
    int i,j,k;

    double const pi=3.14;

    for(k=0;k<200;k++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<200;j++)
        {
            for(i=0;i<200;i++)
            {
                a[i][j][k]=sin(1.5*pi*i)*cos(3.5*pi*j)*k;
                b[i][j][k]=cos(1.5*pi*i)*cos(2.5*pi*k)*j;
                c[i][j][k]=a[i][j][k]-b[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just an aside. Header file `math.h` has a macro `M_PI`, so that is one less detail you need to worry about. You can change your `pi` line to `double const pi = M_PI;` or just use `M_PI` directly everywhere. I prefer the former option.

Comment: Seconding David Alber's comment. Use a pre-existing pi (or any constant like this.) `3.14` is a relatively bad approximation. As an aside, I once saw someone define pi as `double my_pi = 22.0/7.0;` and then put in a fudge factor when things weren't coming out right.

Comment: One piece of advice: If your program doesn't work, it's **YOUR** fault, not the CPU nor the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function can help you:

```
double ***alloc3d(int l, int m, int n) {
    double *data = new double [l*m*n];
    double ***array = new double **[l];
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
        array[i] = new double *[m];
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
            array[i][j] = &(data[(i*m+j)*n]);
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The three arrays require about 190MB of space, which almost certainly exceeds the stack size limit imposed by your operating system.

Try allocating them on the heap (using `new`) instead of placing them on the stack.

Comment: Definitely would not be 8MB. 200*200*200 = 8Mega and a double is probably 8 Bytes and at least 1 Byte and there are 3 of these variables.  Unless he's on an architecture where doubles are represented by one bit.

Comment: 200*200*200*8*3/2^20 yields approximately 183 megabytes.

Comment: Another idea is to allocate them in the "global" area. In the OP's example, move them outside of `main()`.

Comment: I said that the available stack is 8MB not used one... sorry if it's not clear...

Answer (score 2):

You're putting huge arrays of double onto the stack (presumably, assuming that's how your architecture does local variables). Almost surely your system's stack can't hold that much space.

Instead, use vectors instead to allocate on the heap:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double> > > a(200, std::vector<std::vector<double> >(200, std::vector<double>(200)));
```

Comment: double (*a)[200][200]=new double [200][200][200];is the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

stack overflow -> segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

for a non symmetric case we must use this:

```
    double*** a=new double**[IE];
    for(int i=0;i<IE;i++){
        a[i]=new double *[JE];
        for(int j=0;j<JE;j++){
            a[i][j]=new double [KE];
        }
    }
```

with above code we can build huge matrixes as  our computer's ram allows.