# How to pass many arrays to a function effectively?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to work with arrays,with so many arrays My question is that is it possible to access them with their names. For example I have this arrays a1,a2,a3,...,a40 and I want to pass them into a function is it possible to save their names in an another variable and pass that variable to my code or I have to write all arrays in my function arguments?something like this:

```
 double function(double ***a1,double ***a2,....,double ***a40)
 {
  .....
  }
```

I want to do something like this:

```
  char names[40]={a1,...,a[40]};
       double function(char names)
 {
  .....
  }
```

Notice that I want my function acts on arrays(a1,a2,...)

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer:  I'm not sure particularly what, but you're doing something wrong.  You either need a multidimensional array (my guess), or a hash table.  Can you explain your end goal a bit more?  This is a bit of an odd question, and not something C++ supports.

Comment: All problems can be solved by another level of indirection: `double function(double**** arrays, int num = 40);` :P

Comment: @Corbin I have a lot of 3D arrays I just want to instead of writing them with my hand pass their names into a variable and use that name instead of those arrays.suppose I have a for loop that acts on my arrays it is horrible to write something like this a1[i][j][k]=i+j;a2[i][j][k]=-k;a3....

Comment: What are you trying to model with the `double***`?

Comment: @Kaiged I try to model interaction of light with matter for 3D objects such as impinging of an electromagnetic wave with a dielectric sphere.

Comment: @ehsan: Since this is C++, you could use a `class` to model that, hiding the internal representation and providing methods to manipulate each one.  Once that is done, it wouldn't be as complicated to operate on collections of instances of that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hash_map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d462wfh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
myMap["a10"] = 5.0;
```

Comment: Can I use hash_map with g++ compiler?

Comment: I don't know, I use Visual Studio; it works in Visual Studio, if that's any consolation.

Comment: With g++ 4.4.5 (and using its -std=c++0x option) you certainly get TR1's std::unordered_map (which uses a hash).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double* arrays[] = {a1, ..., a40};

double function (double* arrays[])
{
  ...
}
```

**Explanation**

`double* array[]` declares an array of pointer to doubles.  Assuming `a1`, ..., `a40` are arrays of doubles, you can use them to initialize the `arrays` array (arrays and pointers are somewhat synonymous)

Then in the function you take this array and can reference each element like `arrays[0]` (which would be equivalent to `a1`), ..., `arrays[39]` (which is equivalent to `a40`).

I notice you have tree levels of pointer indirection in the types of `a1`, ..., `a40` in the original version of the function.  If this is indeed the case, you can replace `double*` above with `double***`.  This looks very suspicious, though -- it is really hard to handle so many dimentions correctly.

Also, what I am suggesting above is using the *addresses*, not the *names* of the arrays(*).  The names are only for the programmer, once you compile your program, they are not present in the executable, so you cannot refer to them by name.  Their address, however is perfectly usable.

(*) Technically the array itself can be though of as a pointer (thus address), so the above terminology is slightly incorrect, but will help you to understand better what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash of their names as suggested above, or just add more `*`.

```
void f(double*** a, double*** b)
{
   double*** r = b;
   b = a;
   a = r;
};

void g(double**** ar)
{
   double*** t = ar[0];
   ar[1] = ar[0];
   ar[0] = t;
}

double a_ = 0, b_ = 0;
double* pa_ = &a_, *pb_ = &b_;
double** ppa_ = &pa_, **ppb_ = &pb_;

double*** arr[2] = {&ppa_, &ppb_};

f(&ppa_, &ppb_);
g(arr);
```

But as you can see, that get's rather unwieldy (`****`, wow!).  Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish with so many triple pointers flying around your code?  It makes my head hurt.

Comment: It is for 3D simulation each * is for one dimension (x,y,z)

Comment: :D This answers his direct question, but I didn't say I condone it.

Comment: @CodyGray when I want to work with 3D problems I use *** suppose you have a cubic and mesh that cubic into 100 points in each direction now you have 1000,000 points, how can you save these points' information with less *?

Comment: @ehsan: So, the problem is you think pointers are the same as *arrays*?

Comment: @CodyGray it is the only way that I found for avoiding segmentation fault problem. can you suggest another way I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ehsan: I would suggest using *arrays*. Or better yet, since this is C++ rather than C, using a standard container like `std::vector`.

Comment: @CodyGray could you please give me an example that makes a 3d 200*25*200 with std::vector ?

Comment: @Cody Gray: I agree, but it looks like ehsan is using very large arrays [see his other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636638/large-matrix-computation) that exceed the stack size in his environment, thus he is allocating the 3D arrays on the heap with new.

Comment: @Kaiged: An object of type `std::vector` can also be allocated on the heap.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Ah, I was referring to the suggestion of using _arrays_, and didn't see your suggestion of _vectors_.  It seems like his question is really about how to model "very large" 3D arrays and interact with them.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered how to use maps to operate on a desired `double***`, but perhaps just a collection of `double***`s is necessary in this case.  A `typedef double*** Array3d` can help with the confusion.  With this, defining functions to operate on the arrays is more clear:

```
typedef double*** Array3d;

//Operate on a single 3d array
void function( Array3d array )
{
  //Do something...  array[x][y][z] +-*/= whatever;
}

//Operate on a collection of 3d arrays.
void function2( Array3d arrays[] )
{
  for( unsigned int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++ )
  {
    //Do something per array... arrays[i][x][y][z] +-*/= whatever;
  }
}
```

Using standard containers such as `std::vector`, if feasible, would be an even better choice.